# Text box display when click on the edit button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to display the text boxes and list boxes when click on the edit button. Please give suggestion to how to do that things.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="textboxes">
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" id="txt" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="txt" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="txt" /></li>
</ul>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Edit" id="editBut" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("input[type='text']").blur(function(){
    $(this).hide().after('<span class="dfk">' + $(this).val() + '</span>');
});
```

Here js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/yvNuC/11/

Thanks

Comment: Since the code is not huge, could you please put it into your question, for future passers by?

Comment: What do you mean display them on click? They are already displayed. Do you want them hidden by default and then displayed on click? Also, you can only have one ID per item in an HTML document, you have all three list items the same ID. Your question needs to be more specific, I'm sure I could answer it if I could figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#editBut").click(function() {
 $('.textboxes span').hide();
 $('.textboxes input[type=text]').show();
```

});

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yvNuC/22/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/yvNuC/14/

```
$("#editBut").click(function() {
      if ($('.textboxes').is(':visible')) {
         $('.textboxes').hide();
         // do save info
         $(this).val('Edit');
     }
     else {
         $('.textboxes').show();
         $(this).val('Save');
     }        
});
```

Or if you need to display values after saving: http://jsfiddle.net/yvNuC/16/